# how to select distinct with paging in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, pagination, sql-order-by, distinct

how to select distinct with paging in entity framework?
i try to code below

```
 var ll = _ctx.Cwzz_AccVouchMain.Select(v => v.Ddate).Distinct();
        var l = ll.Skip(start).Take(limit).ToList();
```

but error:
must call orderBy method before skip

but my try

```
var ll = _ctx.Cwzz_AccVouchMain.Select(v => v.Ddate).Distinct();
        var l = ll.OrderBy(v => v.Year).ThenBy(v => v.Month).ThenBy(v => v.Date).Skip(start).Take(limit).ToList();
```

error
ystem.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities not suppor type of "Date”。only support initial settlement,entity memeber,entity navagation property.

how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
var ll = _ctx.Cwzz_AccVouchMain.Select(v => v.Ddate).Distinct();
var l = ll.OrderBy(v => v).Skip(start).Take(limit).ToList();
```

When you try to order by year, month and date, your query is not yet executed, and when `.ToList()` triggers it, it tries to build the appropriate sql query before sending it to your database server. However, your db has no clue about a `Ddate.Year`, `Ddate.Month` or `Ddate.Date`, because on the db side the `Ddate` field is a simple date, he doesn't understand your object with properties like the `DateTime` you use in C#.

If you wanted to order by month only (for example), you would have to trigger your query before that.